# Compiling Box2D HelloWorld on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, box2d

I am planning to use `Box2D` in my C++ project. I have downloaded the latest version (v2.3.0.7 when asking this question) of `Box2D` and built it successfully. I can run the Testbed without any errors.

Now, I am trying to build the `HelloWorld.cpp` example, which resides in `HelloWorld` folder in `Box2D` source files but I can't compile this example.

Below is my command for compiling:

```
g++ -g -Wall -L/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/Box2D_v2.3.0/Box2D/Build/Box2D -lBox2D -I/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/Box2D_v2.3.0/Box2D HelloWorld.cpp -o Hello
```

And this is the output I get:

```
/tmp/cc2U314E.o: In function `main':
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:37: undefined reference to `b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:46: undefined reference to `b2World::CreateBody(b2BodyDef const*)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:52: undefined reference to `b2PolygonShape::SetAsBox(float, float)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:55: undefined reference to `b2Body::CreateFixture(b2Shape const*, float)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:61: undefined reference to `b2World::CreateBody(b2BodyDef const*)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:65: undefined reference to `b2PolygonShape::SetAsBox(float, float)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:78: undefined reference to `b2Body::CreateFixture(b2FixtureDef const*)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:92: undefined reference to `b2World::Step(float, int, int)'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:104: undefined reference to `b2World::~b2World()'
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/test/HelloWorld.cpp:104: undefined reference to `b2World::~b2World()'
/tmp/cc2U314E.o: In function `b2PolygonShape':
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/Box2D_v2.3.0/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.h:87: undefined reference to `vtable for b2PolygonShape'
/tmp/cc2U314E.o: In function `~b2PolygonShape':
/home/viki/Desktop/collision_test/Box2D_v2.3.0/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.h:28: undefined reference to `vtable for b2PolygonShape'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using

- `-L` flag for searching for `libBox2D.a`
- `-l` flag for linking `Box2D`
- `-I` flag for pointing to the `Box2D` headers directory

What am I missing? Is there any specific library or command argument I am supposed to add?

Comment: did you run `make install` after making it?

Comment: @MoKi, 

Now I run `make install` within Build folder.

It created install_manifest.txt file, so it copied necessary header files to /usr/local/include/Box2D folder and static libraries into the /usr/local/lib folder.

But i'm still getting the same complaints from g++

Comment: if you compile your project with this command `cmake -DBOX2D_INSTALL=ON -DBOX2D_BUILD_SHARED=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/Box2D ..` you have already specified a path for installation. just run `sudo make install` if you have root privileges. this should resolve your problems and install the libraries where your compiler and linker will look for default. also if you look at `HelloWorld.cpp` there is a line `#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>` this means your header file should be where the libraries are installed in your system which could be `/usr/lib`

Comment: also if your compiler is not looking at the folders you mentioned `/usr/local/include/Box2D` or `/usr/local/lib` then you must use `-I` and `-L` to tell the compiler to look at those locations before looking at the standard locations. run this command to see where the search for headers start `gcc -xc -v -` to see where your compiler looks

Comment: as an example compile your source code like this `g++ main.cpp -o main -xc -v` your compiler will be verbose and prints a lot of information about where it looks for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the -lBox2D behind the HelloWorld.cpp

Comment: hmm... it worked for me. I tried the command as in your question and got the same error as you, then I moved the -lBox2D to the end of the command and it built ok.

Comment: You are right !! After i run `sudo make install` , now i can compile&link HelloWorld.cpp with `g++ HelloWorld.cpp -o Hello -lBox2D`. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If you have built your project properly the `HelloWorld` example will be automatically built for you. There's a `CMakeLists.txt` file in the example folder just run `cmake CMakeLists.txt` in the folder and then run `make`. Prior to this you must have built and installed `Box2D` library. Here is what I did:

I entered the `Build` directory within the `Box2D` and typed the following command:

`cmake -DBOX2D_INSTALL=ON -DBOX2D_BUILD_SHARED=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/Box2D ..`

Then I went one level up to `Box2D` directory and ran `make` then `sudo make install`.

Then I entered the `HelloWorld` directory and it was automatically built. I didn't have to build it manually. Also this is the output from `make` that showed the example was built:

`Linking CXX static library libBox2D.a
[ 42%] Built target Box2D
[ 43%] Building CXX object HelloWorld/CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/HelloWorld.cpp.o`

Comment: Yes, HelloWorld example built when I build the project. But how will I compile another project? 
Am i dependent to Cmakelists.txt ?

Comment: no you are not dependent on cmake for your project you can you any tools you like but this project is using cmake to find the necessary libraries and dependencies during compile time. do you have any difficulty in compiling and using libraries?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i didn't run `sudo make install`. After this @hllnll ' s suggestion worked for me! I'll up vote this when i got more rep.

Comment: @salik well, your main problem was the unavailability of the required library, object files and headers at correct time (the compile time) and correct location as it was clear from the description of your problem and without them you would not be able to compile anything regardless of correct or incorrect g++ command. Anyways I'm glad your problem is solved. After all, we are here to answer questions and solve problems not collect reputation points as rewarding as it could be :)